# How do I ensure saveImage() works across different environments (with spatie/pdf-to-image)?

Tags: laravel, ghostscript

I'm building a Laravel application which has the functionality to auto-generate thumbnail images from PDF files uploaded by user.

Using [spatie/pdf-to-image](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image).

```
$preview_img = $pdf->setPage(1)->setOutputFormat('png')->saveImage($path.'/'.$filename);
```

**[Error] No GS-Path set when trying to call saveImage() function.**

Workaround by setting GS Path following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lhM7m_oHj4&ab_channel=Engineer%27sCommunityGuide

```
Ghostscript::setGsPath("C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64c.exe");
```

However, how do I ensure that Ghostscript still works across different environments (especially *production*) without having to download the GS files seperately for different environments?

Comment: Did you find a solution?